# Login Authentication with Devise (rails) & Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, ionic-framework

I currently have a mobile application where you can create issues, and view a list of issues others have created around your location.

The mobile app is is talking to a rails server and properly creating issues, and I have [followed this guide](http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/26/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-two) covering Authentication with Rails & Devise.

In my `controllers/app.js` file, I have a local variable stored `isLoggedIn` that is set to false by default. When the application is loaded, I check to see whether the variable is true and if so, send the user to `app.issues`. Otherwise, the user is sent to `app.auth.login`.

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
  isLoggedIn: false
});

$scope.$watch('$storage.isLoggedIn', function() {
    if ($scope.$storage.isLoggedIn){
      console.log('is logged in');
      $state.go('app.issues');
    }
    else {
      console.log('isnt logged in');
      $state.go('app.auth.login');
    }
  });
```

Here is my root `app.js` file in my `js` folder.

```
angular.module('orangecone', ['ionic', 'orangecone.controllers', 'orangecone.services', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage', 'ngResource'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.value('Constants', {
  serverUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/'
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('app.issues', {
    url: '/issues',
    views: {
      'app-issues': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/issues.html',
        controller: 'IssuesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.issue', {
    url: '/issues/:issueId',
    views: {
      'app-issues': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/issue.html',
        controller: 'IssueCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/auth/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('app.auth.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/auth/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.auth.register', {
    url: '/register',
    views: {
      'register': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/auth/register.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      }
    }
  })


  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/auth/login');

});
```

I have a waning feeling that I am overlooking something rather trivial. The application always console.logs `logged in` even though the rails server is wiped and there are no users in the system at all. The application should be redirecting the user to `app/auth/login` but never does. Whenever I type this URL into the browser it also redirects me to the `app/issues` page.

Any thoughts or opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you're using API integration with your front end then it'll be better to use https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth instead of `devise` gem

Comment: `devise_token_auth` is also `devise` despite of some modifications to make `devise` work with APIs